# How kubernetes HPA with 2 or more metrics behaves - especially the no.of replicas calculation?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, google-kubernetes-engine

We have configured to use 2 metrics for HPA

1. CPU Utilization
2. App specific custom metrics

When testing, we observed the scaling happening, but calculation of no.of replicas is not very clear. I am not able to locate any documentation on this.

**Questions:**

1. Can someone point to documentation or code on the calculation part?
2. Is it a good practice to use multiple metrics for scaling?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work

> If multiple metrics are specified in a HorizontalPodAutoscaler, this calculation is done for each metric, and then the largest of the desired replica counts is chosen. If any of those metrics cannot be converted into a desired replica count (e.g. due to an error fetching the metrics from the metrics APIs), scaling is skipped.
>
> Finally, just before HPA scales the target, the scale recommendation is recorded. The controller considers all recommendations within a configurable window choosing the highest recommendation from within that window. This value can be configured using the `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization-window` flag, which defaults to 5 minutes. This means that scaledowns will occur gradually, smoothing out the impact of rapidly fluctuating metric values

Comment: what is the meaning of giving same link like kubernetes documents showing. How to set this parameters that should be explained with example like :  `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-delay=3m0s` similarly --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-downscale-stabilization-window= ??`

Comment: The latest docs have a helpful clarification of the last sentence of the first paragraph.  “If any of these metrics cannot be converted into a desired replica count (e.g. due to an error fetching the metrics from the metrics APIs) and a scale down is suggested by the metrics which can be fetched, scaling is skipped. This means that the HPA is still capable of scaling up if one or more metrics give a desiredReplicas greater than the current value.”